# How to make where condition include nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I find ActiveRecord, funnel value is not "input" value

and I make  **where condition**

here is my code

```
@calls = Call.searchable.where.not(funnel: "input")
```

these command work good, but result is also except nil value

I wanna only  **funnel is not 'input'**

how to add OR condition in where statement

SQL Statement is

```
select * from call where is_visible = 1 and (funnel != 'input or funnel is null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blow code should help you.

```
@calls = Call.searchable.where("funnel != 'input' or funnel is null")
```

Comment: No need to parameterize the query if you have plain string, can be written as: `Call.searchable.where("funnel != 'input' or funnel is null")`.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work if values are dynamic

```
Call.searchable.where("funnel != ? OR funnel is ?”,@value1, nil)
```